# Entity of type 'ReportType' named 'Authorize_Change_Reports/X08a_Open_Requests_by_BBB' cannot be found

Tags: reporting

I am facing reports while migrating Via ANT tool.

> [sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'ReportType' named 'Authorize_Change_Reports/X08a_Open_Requests_by_BBB' cannot be found
>   [sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity of type 'ReportType' named 'Authorize_Change_Reports/X07a_Open_Requests_by_QQQQ' cannot be found

I used package.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Authorize_Change_Reports/X08a_Open_Requests_by_BBB</members>
        <members>Authorize_Change_Reports/X07a_Open_Requests_by_QQQQ</members>
        <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

On My Dev Box - These reports are present from where I am fetching the Reports

This is the Report Unique name.

1. X08a_Open_Requests_by_BBB
2. X07a_Open_Requests_by_QQQQ

Note: These reports are developed using Case object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReportType` is not the correct metadata type to migrate Reports. Your `package.xml` should be using the type `Report`.